# I will make a tree structure starting from a father-son dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

```
{'6690': [6620, 3618, 5547, 6660],
   '6620': [6303, 5199, 6293, 6597],
   '3618': [3616],
   '5547': [4137],
   '6660': [6621, 4138, 3558, 3556]
```

goodmorning, I have a data structure like that show above.
I would like to create, starting from this structure, a tree structure in which the parent-child hierarchy is represented.
For instance:

```
6690
--- 6620
---- 6303
---- 5199
---- 6293
---- 6597
--3618
---- 3616
--5574
---- 4137
--- 6660
---- 6621
---- 4138
---- 3558
---- 3556
```

how can i run it in python?

Comment: Since this is not Python code you can't run it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tree data structure then print in depth first manner

```py
d = {'6690': [6620, 3618, 5547, 6660],
   '6620': [6303, 5199, 6293, 6597],
   '3618': [3616],
   '5547': [4137],
   '6660': [6621, 4138, 3558, 3556]
    }

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=None, children=None):
        self.children = [] if children is None else children
        self.val = val
        
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.map = {}
        
    def depth_first_print(self, node=None, depth=0):
        node = self.root if node is None else node
        print('--'*depth, node.val)
        for each_children in node.children:
            self.depth_first_print(each_children, depth+1)
            

nodes = set(map(str, {j for i in d.values() for j in i}.union(set(d.keys()))))

t = Tree()
for each_node in nodes:
    t.map[each_node] = Node(val=each_node)
    
t.root = t.map['6690']

for k, v in d.items():
    for each_child in v:
        t.map[str(k)].children.append(t.map[str(each_child)])
        
        
t.depth_first_print()

#  6690
# -- 6620
# ---- 6303
# ---- 5199
# ---- 6293
# ---- 6597
# -- 3618
# ---- 3616
# -- 5547
# ---- 4137
# -- 6660
# ---- 6621
# ---- 4138
# ---- 3558
# ---- 3556
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key of the first dictionary entry is the oldest ancestor,

then

1. you must first define a node
2. build the tree recursively

```
father_son = {'6690': [6620, 3618, 5547, 6660],
   '6620': [6303, 5199, 6293, 6597],
   '3618': [3616],
   '5547': [4137],
   '6660': [6621, 4138, 3558, 3556]}

# 1) arbitrary node definition
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

# 2) building tree recursively
def build_tree(parent):
    node = Node(parent, [])
    
    if parent in father_son:
        for child in father_son[parent]:
            node.children.append(build_tree(child))
    
    return node


# 3) call the above function to build tree

oldest = next(iter(father_son.keys()))  # returns 6690 in this example
root = build_tree(oldest)
```